# Find a superior alternative to Backward Euler method

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, algorithms, computational-mathematics, runge-kutta-methods

Currently, we are using the backward Euler (or implicit Euler) method for the solution of **stiff** ordinary differential equations during scientific computing.

Assuming a quite performant computer hardware and an identical step size which is smaller than 100us. Are there other **stable** integration methods that are able to compute `y(n+1)` in just **one time step** (real-time) and have lower truncation errors? What are their pros and cons?

I would like to implement the most promising ones and benchmark their results.

External references:

[Numerical Solution of Ordinary Diﬀerential Equations](https://people.maths.ox.ac.uk/suli/nsodes.pdf)

[One-Step Methods: Chapter 3.3](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0ahUKEwjm0J2EzIDUAhXIK8AKHSuFCIMQFggtMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.cs.rpi.edu%2F~flaherje%2Fpdf%2Fode3.pdf&usg=AFQjCNG_bsaC5pUmkr8XTcKBWFSAAyoJhg&cad=rja)

[John Butcher´s Tutorials](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0ahUKEwis19PpzoDUAhWZF8AKHbDKBSQQFghDMAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.math.auckland.ac.nz%2F~butcher%2FODE-book-2008%2FTutorials%2FIRK.pdf&usg=AFQjCNEir7EG9WEcXkLFLat8_80eBt_OPA&cad=rja)

Comment: Runge-Kutta is one of the first traditionally introduced at least when I was a student https://nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runge-Kuttamethode

Comment: However if you want something more powerful you should probably consider some implicit scheme, although not sure to be $O(1)$, they can usually perform better and more stable.

Comment: Runge Kutta as described on Wikipedia is already O(1) in time. Constant number of passes with each being constant with respect to the data.

Comment: The implicit trapezoidal method is only a slight variation of the backward Euler method. Are you sure that you have to exclude it?

Comment: Is there a [predictor-corrector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Predictor%E2%80%93corrector_method?wprov=sfla1) scheme that meets your requirements? First-order in time is pretty restrictive; there are many second-order methods with superior accuracy and stability using very little added computation. You may also be interested in local-linearization integration. In brief: rather than *approximately integrating* $\frac{dx}{dt} = f(x)$, we can linearize $f(x) \approx \frac{df}{dx}\Big{|}_{x=x_{i-1}}(x - x_{i-1})$ and then apply one timestep of the *analytical solution* to $\frac{dx}{dt} = Fx$.

Comment: By "order one in time", I assume you mean a method with first-order accuracy? If so, then by definition every first-order method will have exactly the same behavior of local truncation error, $\tau = O(\Delta t^2)$, so I'm not sure I understand the question.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately I need to exclude them since two computation steps are already too much in our scenario.

Comment: @Rahul That's really interesting. I am not from the field but if this is the case than this would be the answer to the question. In that case it would not be possible to find a superior alternative to the Backward Euler method. How about the global truncation error?

Comment: How do you do backwards Euler in one step? Is your equation linear? Usually solving $y_{n+1}=y_n+hf(t_{n+1},y_{n+1})$ requires an iteration of some kind, be it simple fixed point or Newton.

Comment: @LutzL Yes, it is linear. Well, the more I dive in here, the more I guess that I am pretty lost. I am basically open to anything, but I only have this one time step to do the computation. As I said, the goal is to make the absolute truncation errors (local+global) as small as possible.

Comment: Updated the original question and added an intersting external reference. If someone has a good understanding of possible one-step methods, he or she could provide a small overview as a first answer to be used for further discussion.

Comment: A guy named Gear wrote a good book which covers this.  Google it.

Comment: Gear, William,*Numerical Initial Value Problems in Ordunary Differential Equations*

Comment: The phrase "compute in just one time step" is confusing. Does this mean solving in real-time? That would depend on the computer hardware.

Comment: @jnez71 exactly!

Comment: Then your question is kinda under-defined. For example, I can propose a super computer that can carry out *any* algorithm's iteration in under 100us. Or I can propose a slow computer where even implicit Euler is too much work to accomplish in 100us.

Comment: Maybe you want to specify the maximum number of FLOPs the computer can carry out per timestep?

Comment: You are right. Please assume that dedicated real-time hardware is in place which can do quite a lot in 100us.

Comment: I don't know the FLOPs to be honest. However, backward Euler is absolutely no problem an there are definitely ressources for more advanced alhorithms. But no, we unfortunately do not have a super computer.

Comment: @MilkMan The [central difference formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference_coefficient#Central_finite_difference) might be what you are after.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are currently using backwards Euler for a linear ODE $\dot y=Ay+b$, then you are solving in every step
$$
\Bigl(I-hA(t_n+h)\Bigr)\,y_{n+1} = y_n+hb(t_n+h)
$$
If $A$ is constant, that is one matrix factorization at initialization and the corresponding backwards substitutions per step.

Using the implicit trapezoidal formula
$$
y_{n+1}=y_n+\frac h2(f(t_n,y_n)+f(t_n+h,y_{n+1}))
$$
requires to solve for the linear equation the system
$$
\left(I-\frac h2 A(t_n+h)\right)y_{n+1}=\left(I+\frac h2A(t_n)\right)y_n+\frac h2\left(b(t_n)+b(t_n+h)\right)
$$
Compared to the method before, this has one additional matrix-vector multiplication, which is not that much effort, especially if $A$ is sparse. And a bit more organization and storage, which is a concern at coding time and does not materially influence the run-time.

---

(*3/27/2021*) The third order DiagIRK method that can be found in the cited slides of Butcher (IRK.pdf, slide 25) combines 3 stages where each is essentially equivalent to an implicit Euler step. The difference in orders means that, approximately, where implicit Euler needs 1000 steps of step size $10^{-3}$ to get an error $10^{-3}$, the DiagIRK method would only need step size $0.1$ with 10 steps amounting to 30 Euler-equivalent computations. If one reduces the targeted error, the difference becomes even more pronounced, to get to $10^{-6}$, it is $10^6$ Euler steps vs. 300 Euler-equivalent steps in DiagIRK.

Comment: Thank you very much for this. Could you please explain a little the benefits of the implicit trapezoidal method compared to the implicit Euler method?

Comment: It is order 2, it is the best you can do with using only values at $t_n$ and $t_{n+1}$, its stability region is still the negative half-plane, it is part of the widely used Crank-Nicholson method,...

Comment: Ok. Now we are getting closer... I have added two more external references. There, it is mentioned that implicit multi-stage Runge-Kutta methods (and if I understood correctly, implicit Euler and implicit trapezoidal are belonging to that class of methods) could be used for my task.

Comment: So, a question to the Runge-Kutta experts: Are there maybe other promising one-step methods of that class (e.g. Gauss–Legendre methods) that I should evaluate together with the implicit trapezoidal method?

Comment: You might want to explore exponential methods (see google/wikipedia) and DIRK, see https://www.math.auckland.ac.nz/~butcher/ODE-book-2008/Tutorials/IRK.pdf

Comment: Never had to do with DIRK methods so far. Have you already used them? If yes, can you say sth. about their computational cost compairing to implicit Euler method?

Comment: No, it just seems to give maximal results from using just one matrix factorization. Again, if the matrix is constant, the factorization can be computed once before the integration is started.

Comment: May it be that the implicit trapezoidal method introduces a delay of one time step compared to the implicit Euler method? At least my outcomes are looking like that...

Comment: It should not. If you observe that it would be worth opening a new question with a small example and code for both methods that demonstrates that behavior. But it might also be that you observe the usual imprecisions of first order methods, did you try varying the step-size?